# Any trick to removing GU10 lightbulbs?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, safety, bulb, halogen

I'm trying to remove some halogen GU10 lightbulbs.  They are in a space where simply gripping them around the edges is nearly impossible.

Is there any trick to removing these bulbs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's suction cups made just for that. They stick to the front glass and let you turn the bulb.

Just google for "gu10 suction cups".